# strip white spaces and new lines when reading from file

Tags: python, file, split

I have the following code, that successfully strips end of line characters when reading from file, but doesn't do so for any leading and trailing white spaces (I want the spaces in between to be left!)

What is the best way to achieve this? (Note, this is a specific example, so not a duplicate of general methods to strip strings)

**My code**: (try it with the **test data**: "**Mr Moose**" (not found) and if you try **"Mr Moose "** (that is a space after the Moose) it will work.

```
#A COMMON ERROR is leaving in blank spaces and then finding you cannot work with the data in the way you want!

"""Try the following program with the input: Mr Moose
...it doesn't work..........
but if you try "Mr Moose " (that is a space after Moose..."), it will work!
So how to remove both new lines AND leading and trailing spaces when reading from a file into a list. Note, the middle spaces between words must remain?
"""

alldata=[]
col_num=0
teacher_names=[]
delimiter=":"

with open("teacherbook.txt") as f:
      for line in f.readlines():
            alldata.append((line.strip()))
      print(alldata)


      print()
      print()

      for x in alldata: 
             teacher_names.append(x.split(delimiter)[col_num]) 

      teacher=input("Enter teacher you are looking for:")
      if teacher in teacher_names: 
            print("found")
      else:
            print("No")
```

**Desired output**, on producing the list alldata

```
['Mr Moose:Maths', 'Mr Goose:History', 'Mrs Congenelipilling:English']
```

i.e - remove all leading and trailing white space at the start, and before or after the delimiter. The spaces in between words such as Mr Moose, must be left.

**Contents of teacherbook:**

```
Mr Moose : Maths
Mr Goose: History
Mrs Congenelipilling: English
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `teacher_names.append(x.split(delimiter)[col_num].strip())` is that what you want?

Comment: I'm afraid that comes up with [col_num]).strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'  .... but also the preferred solution, as mentioned in the question, is to strip /n AND leading and trailing spaces while reading the lines from the file into alldata (in the first place). Thanks so much!

Comment: Try again with my edited code above (i had the parentheses wrong before)

Comment: What's the contents of `teacherbook.txt`?

Comment: Just added the contents of teacherbook - updated question. Thank you -

Comment: @Chris_Rands - perfect. Yes, this would work, but what I'm after as a solution is to read it in from the file into all_data without /n and leading and trailing spaces, rather than deal with it after - which I assume would be the better solution

Comment: I still can't see the input file data?

Comment: Mr Moose : Maths
Mr Goose: History
Mrs Congenelipilling: English

Comment: @MissComputing: Since it is only determined after the split by the delimiter  which characters are actually leading/trailing whitespace, I'd argue Chris_Rands answer is as close as you'll get.

Comment: agreed, but someone else has just put his exact answer in as their answer ......

Comment: @MissComputing yes, that was me and that was before Chris corrected his typo. You won't get a better answer because there isn't one. And if Chris copies his comment as an answer, I'll remove mine.

Comment: @MissComputing - Could you specify what your desired FINAL outcome is? From how I read your code the "desired outcome" is a mere intermediate step get to the next step of figuring out whether a certain teacher's name is in there. Thus people start suggesting solutions that presumably only mean more code and work for no real practical gain over Chris_Rands approach.

Comment: If you like @Błotosmętek's answer then accept it; I don't mind!Your code could improved in other ways, but this is the line that solves your initial question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a regex:

```
txt='''\
Mr Moose : Maths
Mr Goose: History
Mrs Congenelipilling: English'''

>>> [re.sub(r'\s*:\s*', ':', line).strip() for line in txt.splitlines()]
['Mr Moose:Maths', 'Mr Goose:History', 'Mrs Congenelipilling:English']
```

So your code becomes:

```
import re
col_num=0
teacher_names=[]
delimiter=":"

with open("teacherbook.txt") as f:
    alldata=[re.sub(r'\s*{}\s*'.format(delimiter), delimiter, line).rstrip() for line in f]
    print(alldata)

    for x in alldata: 
         teacher_names.append(x.split(delimiter)[col_num]) 
    print(teacher_names)
```

Prints:

```
['Mr Moose:Maths', 'Mr Goose:History', 'Mrs Congenelipilling:English']
['Mr Moose', 'Mr Goose', 'Mrs Congenelipilling']
```

The key part is the regex:

```
re.sub(r'\s*{}\s*'.format(delimiter), delimiter, line).rstrip()

          ^                          0 to unlimited spaced before the delimiter
            ^                        place for the delimiter
              ^                      unlimited trailing space
```

[Interactive Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xvKucX/1/)

---

For an all Python solution, I would use [str.partition](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to get the left hand and right hand side of the delimiter then strip the whitespace as needed:

```
alldata=[]    
with open("teacherbook.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        lh,sep,rh=line.rstrip().partition(delimiter)
        alldata.append(lh.rstrip() + sep + rh.lstrip())
```

Same output

---

Another suggestion. Your data is more suited to a `dict` than a list.

You can do:

```
di={}
with open("teacherbook.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        lh,sep,rh=line.rstrip().partition(delimiter)
        di[lh.rstrip()]=rh.lstrip()
```

Or comprehension version:

```
with open("teacherbook.txt") as f:
    di={lh.rstrip():rh.lstrip() 
          for lh,_,rh in (line.rstrip().partition(delimiter) for line in f)}
```

Then access like this:

```
>>> di['Mr Moose']
'Maths'
```

Comment: Can you explain [re.sub(r'\s*:\s*', ':', line) character by character...!?

Comment: Much as I love regexes, they are rather expensive. 10000 iterations of my pure python solution versus this pattern matching solution show that this solution is 64x slower (`0.0547`s vs `0.00085`s). I always think that if you can easily avoid a regex pattern, you should, and in this case the pure python solution is a pythonic one-liner.

Comment: Although admittedly the performance difference is trivial for this case. Depends what you are trying to optimise; I personally think the regex is more readable but others may disagree.

Comment: @MissComputing: See edit with re explanation and a simple all Python solution

Comment: Thanks for putting in the python solution - and good shout using `str.partition()`. My only minor gripe is that `''.join(...)` is better than `str + str + str`, but thanks for good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `readlines()`, you can simply iterate through the file object to get each line, and use `strip()` to remove the `\n` and whitespaces. As such, you can use this list comprehension;

```
with open('teacherbook.txt') as f:
    alldata = [':'.join([value.strip() for value in line.split(':')]) 
               for line in f]
    print(alldata)
```

---

Outputs;

```
['Mr Moose:Maths', 'Mr Goose:History', 'Mrs Congenelipilling:English']
```

Comment: Are you able to write it out line by line without using shortcuts (so it is more readable for teaching purposes). I mean, extending out the for loops and such and commenting each line.....?

Comment: While I agree with the comment that `f.readlines()` is not a good pattern, the comment *this will give you each line with the `\n` characters already stripped* is wrong. Try `[line for line in f]`. You are stripping the `\n` with `value.strip()` as well as all leading spaces if that is relevant.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I had never realised this - I suppose I have always used it in conjunction with `strip()`. What I should have said was it splits the file into a list of lines, which is what `readlines()` does anyway, so it removes an unnecessary extra step rather than fixing a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
teacher_names.append(x.split(delimiter)[col_num])
```

to:

```
teacher_names.append(x.split(delimiter)[col_num].strip())
```

Comment: teacher_names.append(x.split(delimiter)[col_num].strip()) is what ChrisRands suggested in his comment a while ago....

Answer (score 2):

> remove all leading and trailing white space at the start, and before or after the delimiter. The spaces in between words such as Mr Moose, must be left.

You can split your string at the delimiter, strip the whitespace from them, and concatenate them back together again:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    new_line = ':'.join([s.strip() for s in line.split(':')])
    alldata.append(new_line)
```

**Example**:

```
>>> lines = ['  Mr Moose :   Maths', ' Mr Goose :  History  ']
>>> lines
['  Mr Moose :   Maths', ' Mr Goose :  History  ']
>>> data = []
>>> for line in lines:
    new_line = ':'.join([s.strip() for s in line.split(':')])
    data.append(new_line)


>>> data
['Mr Moose:Maths', 'Mr Goose:History']
```

Comment: While this is technically correct, it lacks all reason to first split, then concatenate again if it will be split it again (on the same delimiter) anyways.

Comment: @HendrikMakait I'm not sure what you mean exactly? it doesn't lack reason. The reason you are splitting is to remove leading and trailing white-space before each part of the line. You then need to concatenate the stripped parts back together again using the original delimiter. It may seem a little strange, but I'd hardly say it's reason-less.

Comment: I may be wrong (note the comment on the original question asking for clearer specs here), but as far as the code example advances, the data must be split again on the same delimiter to fulfill its purpose. Therefore concatenating it again before the eventual split is simply creating more code and work. I am comparing it with the benchmark of Chris_Rands answer/comment btw.

Comment: Actually, I agree with you there, @Hendrik . It does look like they will later split the data again. _However_, as you noted in your previous comment, I am answering the last question the OP posed in the question. That's why i quoted the question in my answer; to make it clear _what_ exactly I was answering. Also note I was intentionally trying to make my answer general purpose so it could apply future users problems rather than this specific one. But for the OP's specific case, Chris_Rands method is probably better.

Comment: @HendrikMakait I disapproved of your edit because I believe I  had already made it clear what part of the question I was answering; That was the purpose of me quoting the OP's question. I'm leaving it up to the OP and future readers whether or my solution would fit into the original code. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with regex - re.sub:

```
import re

re.sub(r"[\n \t]+$", "", "aaa \t asd \n ")
Out[17]: 'aaa \t asd'
```

first argument pattern - `[`all characters you want to remove`]+`+ - one or more matches`$`$ - end of the string

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score -2):

With string.rstrip('something') you can remove that 'something' from the right end of the string like this:

```
a = 'Mr Moose \n'

print a.rstrip(' \n') # prints 'Mr Moose\n' instead of 'Mr Moose \n\n'
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I was asking for - but thanks for the suggestion (it is useful for others wanting to strip a string). I need to know how to strip newline characters AND leading and trailing spaces when reading a file into a list, leaving the spaces in between intact.

Comment: @MissComputing Your code as it is **does** strip leading and trailing spaces from every line, the problem is you also want to strip spaces between the teacher's name and the delimiter, which your code doesn't do.

Comment: Try using `raw_input` instead of `input`. 

As far as I can tell the splitting of the string seems to work properly, since 

`a = 'Mr Moose:Maths'
b = 'Mr Moose'

print b == a.split(':')[0]`

yields true....

Comment: Isn't raw_input only for Python 2? (not Python 3?)

Comment: Oh, true, since you didn't specify which python version you are using I've tried it in Python 2.7, in which case you would have to use `raw_input`